# CentOS 7 firewalld errors and warnings after default install

Tags: centos, iptables, firewalld

My VPS provided a minimal CentOS 7 install which did not come with firewalld pre-installed.

This question is related to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/411565/centos-7-firewall-defaultly-not-working)

I installed it and had the following errors at startup:

```
# systemctl enable firewalld.service
# systemctl start firewalld
# systemctl status firewalld
* firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-08-20 17:54:23 EDT; 5s ago
     Docs: man:firewalld(1)
 Main PID: 756 (firewalld)
   CGroup: /system.slice/firewalld.service
           |-756 /usr/bin/python -Es /usr/sbin/firewalld --nofork --nopid
           `-800 /usr/bin/python -Es /usr/sbin/firewalld --nofork --nopid

Aug 20 17:54:22 server systemd[1]: Starting firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon...
Aug 20 17:54:23 server systemd[1]: Started firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon.
Aug 20 17:54:26 server firewalld[756]: WARNING: ipset not usable, disabling ipset usage in firewall.
Aug 20 17:54:27 server firewalld[756]: ERROR: Failed to read file "/proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_helper": [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_helper'
Aug 20 17:54:27 server firewalld[756]: WARNING: Failed to get and parse nf_conntrack_helper setting
Aug 20 17:54:27 server firewalld[756]: WARNING: ebtables not usable, disabling ethernet bridge firewall.
```

I installed iptables and restarted the firewalld service but receive the exact same error. I did a full `dnf update` and rebooted and still have the same error.

I tried the answer from the other thread suggesting that I use `depmod` but I get an error:

```
# depmod
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/2.6.32-042stab120.19: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
```

I have done a minimal install many times on my own metal but this environment seems to be a little different on the VPS. I'm unsure of how to proceed.

What do I need to do to resolve these warnings and error?

---

Story time. My VPS provider uses a non-standard port for SSH (not 22). After installing the service and rebooting, I realized that I forgot to open that port. I'd locked myself out!

My provider also provides a web interface for a serial console so I was able to get back in and open the port. But this also tells me that the firewall seems to be working.

---

How does the firewall's current state affect its ability to function otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

You could be using old kernel. Check your kernel version. It must be 3.10 or above

```
$ uname -a
```

More details here: [FirewallD on Github](https://github.com/firewalld/firewalld/issues/443)